I am facing issue while using AltTester unity sdk
Using this library in C# script while writing test cases in unity c# script
using Altom.AltUnityDriver;

we face the error ,
type or namespace name 'Altom' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

How to resolve this? Has any body faced this issue?
I have tried to fix it but could not found any solution and i am expecting the proper solution to solve this issue.

Have a read of this.

Check your .net reference DLL Version and project .net version.
If Mismatch recompile the target version
